# How to reset form using selenium webdriver in python and submit form

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a signup form I'm testing using Selenium. After the form page loads, using jQuery, I reset the form fields by using `$('input[input!='submit']', 'select').val('')` following which all the mandatory fields are entered via selenium. Finally when all required fields are entered and the submit button is clicked, nothing happens! Note: I can see that the selenium click event has triggered (as the button is highlighted) but the page doesn't load the resulting page.

If I try manually on a normal browser using the same jQuery followed by clicking the submit button it works fine. Also, I looked back at the submit button's HTML content and it's unchanged after the jQuery execution.

```
<input type="submit" value="doThat" name="submit">
```

Comment: In Java, I often use something like `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form")).submit()` and `....clear()`. Can you get at that from Python?

Comment: @SiKing, yes that is available.

Comment: I've tried that but the problem is that I don't want to do a clear() for every field so I used jQuery to clear all fields

Answer (score 0):

1. You have some typos.

   (1) The attribute of the input element, is `type`, not the same `input`.

   ```
   <input type='submit'>  
   bad: $('input[type=input]')
   good: $('input[type=submit]')
   ```

   (2) Must pass to jQuery one string, not a several strings:

   ```
   bad:  jQuery('input', 'select')
   good: jQuery('input, select')
   ```

   (3) To assign the empty value .val('') to the select, the empty one has to be one of the select options.

   ```
   bad:  SELECT options: ['a', 'b'] 
   good: SELECT options: ['', 'a', 'b']
   ```

   I'm using python, so it would be correct that way (with **execute_script** use **jQuery** instead of **$** to prevent errors):

   ```
   driver.execute_script(
       "jQuery('input[type!=submit], select').val('');"
   )
   ```
2. For submitting the form, there are two ways:

   (1)by yourself, searching the submit input and .submit() it:

   ```
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type=submit]').submit()
   ```

   (2)or letting selenium search the submit for you (in some html
   structures fails):

   ```
   any_form_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('select')
   any_form_element.submit()
   ```

Comment: I tried all of the above although despite the typo fixes it hasn't worked for me. The clearing up of input fields works properly with my jQuery and with the one you suggested.  What doesn't work for me is the submit button; I tried both the cases you suggested and mine `driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()` and none of them causes the submit to work. I can see the click event taking place as the submit button gets highlighted but the page doesn't submit the form. Let me know if there's any other information I can provide.